# Populate a parameter dropdown based off another parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to populate a dropdown based off another dropdown parameter. I have 5 parameters, but the first 3 populate the 4th in the report. So the 4th and 5th parameter are what the user uses to populate a report. So the 4th parameter (meetings) has a meetings dataset and the 5th parameter is meetingType with a dataset of meetingType. So when the user selects a meeting, then the meetingType gets populated by that selection. Currently both dropdowns produce all results, which I don't want. I just want all results for meetings and then the meetingType gets populated by meeting.

The table it produces once the report is ran doesn't use those properties and there isn't a place to query anything. I can only use available values from each dataset and not use available values based on the selection of the 4th parameter.

Comment: Sounds like you need to refer to your first parameter (or 4th) in the query of the second (or 5th). Assuming it's a query pulling the values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really clear.  do you need a parameter or do you just want to have the meeting type available as a value in your report output?

Fairly straightforward.  You have two datasets, one for each parameter.  You need to filter the second dataset based on the first parameter.
For example, I often create reports that ask for a range of values, let's say programs.  Once the user has entered the beginning value, the ending value must be greater than or equal to the beginning value.  So, on the ending value dataset I create a filter. In this case, the filter says that the field code (which is my program) must be between the starting parameter and the maximum value allowed:
[image: filter]

You can make your filter as complex as needed - referring to the other parameter with a formula

Comment: I have 2 parameters that return all values but I need the 2nd parameter to only return values based on the selection of the dropdown of the 1st parameter

Comment: So I am already doing this for the filtered part. Its not the DataSet thats the problem, this works. Its the 2 parameter dropdowns up top thats the problem. I need the 2 dropdowns to work together, so like in your case with programs, if you select a program start date, the 2nd parameter, which is currently empty, would populate with end dates. does that make sense?

Comment: So you want the second parameter to default based on the first parameter?   Then, change your second dataset to return one value based upon the first parameter.  And then on the parameter setup, use the dataset as the default value, not as the available value

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this via separate datasets for each parameter.

Lets say you have two parameters @`param1` and @`param2`

you want the values on @`param2` to change based on @`param1` selection.

You will have your main dataset (main_dataset) with a where clause something like this

```
where sometable.somecolumn = @param1
and sometable.someothercolumn = @param2
```

Now you create a dataset (param1_dataset) for @`param1` which brings back all the values you require for this parameter

Now create another dataset (param2_dataset) form @`param2` and add a where clause to it which restricts the returned list.. something like this..

```
where sometable.somecolumn = @param1
```

Now on your report parameters.. set the Available Values for each parameter (report parameter properties) to `"Get Values from a query"` and select the appropriate dataset and the value field and label field (returned by the dataset) for each parameter.

Now when you run your report, your parameter selection 2 should change based on what you selected for parameter selection 1